# Add Data of previous months in next month, HANA Calculated View

Tags: sql, hana

INPUT :

```
 ID  STATUS  YEAR MONTH
    A   OPEN1   2017-01
    A   OPEN2   2017-01
    A   CLOSED  2017-03
    B   OPEN1   2017-01
    B   OPEN2   2017-02
    B   OPEN3   2017-02
    B   Closed  2017-05
```

my output:

IN 2017-02:

(only C COUNTED FOR OPEN1 AS A&B SHIFTED TO diff status) FOR OPEN1

(ONLY A COUNTED(FROM PREV MONTH),b IS in OPEN2)

IN 2017-03:

C IN OPEN1 FROM PREV MONTH

B OPEN FROM PREV MONTH COUNT2

```
YEAR MONTH    COUNT-OPEN1       COUNT-OPEN2      COUNT-CLOSED
2017-01     2(A&B OPEN1)         1(A IN OPEN1)   0
2017-02     1                    2               0
2017-03     1                    1               1(A CLOSED)
2017-04     1                    0               2(A,B CLOSED)
2017-05     1                    0               2
2017-06     1                    0               2
2017-07     1                    0               2
2017-08     1                    0               2
2017-09     1                    0               2
```

I need to add data to open/closed from previous months to upcoming months, is it possible in SAP HANA without use of Cursors? As I can do it with Cursors, if any other logic exist please help me with it!

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this blog and it should be able to help you out.

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/10/how-tocalculate-ytd-mtd-anytd-using-date-dimensions/

Comment: I am not sure how will this help me in adding data from prev month, and subtracting it if it is completed.